# wp_insert_post anonymous poster

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to force a front end form to create an anonymous post or a post with a set user ID

The following is the array I am passing to wp_insert_post

```
array('post_title' => $title, 
      'post_content' => 'Test', 
      'post_status' => 'draft', 
      'post_type' => 'post', 
      'post_author' => 2)
```

When a user is logged out or 'anonymous' I am trying to force post_author as 2 but it doesn't seem to be successful which doesn't seem to be working.

(This is in relation to an ajax request. Answer is below.)

Any support on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot invoke the following action when logged out

```
add_action("wp_ajax_submit_data", "dc_form_submit");
```

you have to use the following

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_data", "dc_form_submit");
```

you must have both actions listed in order for an ajax request to successfully post to admin-ajax.php for logged in and logged out users.

```
add_action("wp_ajax_submit_data", "dc_form_submit");
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_data', "dc_form_submit");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code I would use:

```
<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
}else {
    $userID = 2;
}
$frontEndPost = array(
  'post_title'    => esc_html($title),
  'post_content'  => $content,
  'post_status'   => 'draft',
  'post_author'   => $userID, 
);

wp_insert_post( $frontEndPost );

?>
```

This is tested and works fine, if this is not working I would guess that you are not passing a title to the post.

Comment: All is okay when passing params I think I may have narrowed it down to admin-ajax.php not running correctly when logged out.

Comment: Cody you were correct, I should have given more details on this being an ajax request. Thanks.